# Repeated entries when logging in python

Tags: python, logging

***CONTEXT***

I have written a function that validates the arguments used in my script. My script works and I am now trying to add logging to it using `logging` library.

***CODE***

I have set up my logging using

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='AutoStats.log', level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s %(message)s')
```

The logging in my script works fine using things such as

```
logging.info('IT WORKED!!')
```

However the logging in this function:

```
def valid():
    """ Check to see if the arguments used throughout the script are valid """
    false_count = 0
    for a in argv[1:]:
        if a == date:
            if re.match('^\d{8}$', date):
                logging.info('Date is Valid')
                continue
            else:
                logging.warning('Date parameter was invalid')
                false_count += 1
        if a == raw_dir or a == today_dir or a == archive_dir:
            if a.endswith('\\'):
                logging.info(a + 'is a valid parameter')
                continue
            else:
                logging.warning(a + 'is not a valid paremeter, check formatting')
                false_count += 1
    if false_count > 0:
        logging.warning('One or more of your arguments in the overruling .bat file has been entered in an incorrect format')
        return False
    else:
        logging.info('All parameters validated')
        return True
```

The logging does work, however it is repeated.

Instead of seeing

```
2014-09-23 13:52:42,717 Date is Valid
2014-09-23 13:52:42,717 C:\dev\OTQtxt\Correct_Ver\RAW_OTQ\is a valid parameter
2014-09-23 13:52:42,717 C:\dev\OTQtxt\Correct_Ver\today\is a valid parameter
2014-09-23 13:52:42,717 C:\dev\OTQtxt\Correct_Ver\archive\is a valid parameter
2014-09-23 13:52:42,717 All parameters validated
```

Which is what I'd expect, I actually see:

```
2014-09-23 13:52:42,717 Date is Valid
2014-09-23 13:52:42,717 C:\dev\OTQtxt\Correct_Ver\RAW_OTQ\is a valid parameter
2014-09-23 13:52:42,717 C:\dev\OTQtxt\Correct_Ver\today\is a valid parameter
2014-09-23 13:52:42,717 C:\dev\OTQtxt\Correct_Ver\archive\is a valid parameter
2014-09-23 13:52:42,717 All parameters validated
2014-09-23 13:52:42,717 Date is Valid
2014-09-23 13:52:42,717 C:\dev\OTQtxt\Correct_Ver\RAW_OTQ\is a valid parameter
2014-09-23 13:52:42,717 C:\dev\OTQtxt\Correct_Ver\today\is a valid parameter
2014-09-23 13:52:42,717 C:\dev\OTQtxt\Correct_Ver\archive\is a valid parameter
2014-09-23 13:52:42,717 All parameters validated
```

I've looked over my script and can't see where it loops over this function twice which would cause it to do this.

Have I placed the `logging.info` calls in the wrong place or wrong level of indentation or is it something else?

***EDIT***

This is how the `valid()` function is called:

```
def main():
    """ Run the defined functions above in a set order to check validation, clear the RAW directory and then concatenate the CSV files. All Functions are run in try/except blocks to catch and record errors"""
    errors = 0
    start = time.time()
    if not valid():
        raise TypeError('One or more of your arguments in the overruling .bat file has been entered in an incorrect format')
    if valid():
        do_stuff()
```

Comment: Where are you calling the `valid()` function?

Comment: You call the `valid()` 2 times. Put the `do_stuff()` inside a `else` block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the `valid()` function twice, instead use `if-else` block.

```
def main():
    """ Run the defined functions above in a set order to check validation, clear the RAW directory and then concatenate the CSV files. All Functions are run in try/except blocks to catch and record errors"""
    errors = 0
    start = time.time()
    if not valid():
        raise TypeError('One or more of your arguments in the overruling .bat file has been entered in an incorrect format')
    else:
        do_stuff()
```

Answer (score 0):

The valid function is called twice hence the error. Try the following code:

```
def main():
    """ Run the defined functions above in a set order to check validation, clear the RAW    directory and then concatenate the CSV files. All Functions are run in try/except blocks to     catch and record errors"""
    errors = 0
    start = time.time()
    valid_output = valid()
    if not valid_output:
        raise TypeError('One or more of your arguments in the overruling .bat file has been entered in an incorrect format')
    if valid_output:
        do_stuff()
```

Comment: this would work, but sk11 has suggested a much sleeker way of doing it. Also, formatting answers properly will help.